# IFileOpenDialog Show method not using input parent HWND

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I have a classic c++ desktop application that uses IFileOpenDialog. I was using Spy++ and noticed that although we call Show with the hWnd of a view, when the dialog shows up, Spy shows me the owner is not the view but rather our top level frame the view is a child of.

The IModalWindow::Show documentation only says the input is the handle of the owner window. I even stepped thru assembly code and verified the hWnd we used was pushed into a register and made it to the called frame.

I have not found any Microsoft documentation that indicates this behavior would occur. I'm not even sure how the system would find the top level parent other than to walk the parent chain until a parent/owner is returned that is the desktop and then using the window whose parent/owner was the desktop. Guess I could hook into GetParent and/or GetWindow to see if those calls are made when we call Show.

Does anyone know about this or see the same thing?

Comment: Yes, the system could easily walk the parent tree until it found the parent whose parent is the desktop. Would not be surprised at all if they implemented it that way. Why would someone want a child window to be the owner of a modal dialog? I don't think I would.

Comment: This behavior is built into `CreateWindow` et al. "Only an overlapped or pop-up window can be an owner window; a child window cannot be an owner window... If `hwndParent` identifies a child window, the system assigns ownership to the top-level parent window of the child window." [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows).